# Pascal. Как проверить, что введенное число, которое больше MaxInt, является кратным 6?

Tags: pascal

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать с числами, которые больше MaxInt? Нужно проверить, кратно ли такое число 6. Не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

во-первых вам надо написать свой функционал для таких чисел

такие большие числа могут представлять собой массив обычных чисел - например INT - это 4 байта (т.е. от 0 до 2^32), а два таких числа дают уже 8 байт (т.е. от 0 до 2^64) и т.д.

идем дальше

для того, чтобы узнать что огромное число делится на 6 нам понадобится такая вещь как **основная теорема арифметики**:

одно из ее следствий - если число делится на взаимно простые числа, то оно делится и на произведение этих чисел

числа 2 и 3 - взаимно простые, значит нам для определения делимости на 6 надо проверить делится ли ваше огромное число на 2 и на 3

**делимость на 2:**

если ваше большое число состоит из `a,b,c,d,...,z` чисел типа INT, то достаточно проверить, что последнее число `z` - чётное

**делимость на 3:**

проверять сумму цифр на делимость на 3 не стоит, можно обойтись более простым подходом - сумма остатков деления чисел `a,b,c,d,...,z`, которые составляют большое число, должно делиться на 3 без остатка (т.е. сумма остатков должна быть 0)

т.е. надо будет `(a mod 3 + b mod 3 + ... + z mod 3) mod 3 = 0` проверить

Comment: Попробую, спасибо за ответ!